# Multi line and space regex issue in c# only

Tags: c#, regex

What is wrong with this code? My goal is to find urls in text and place them into hyperlink tags. I am using old    diegoperini regex (credits https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex). 
Everything goes well if my input is one line and without space in the end.

https://regex101.com/ page shows that this regex is valid (global and multine checked), but c# finds nothing.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String sourcestring = @"Tralala

bla bla bla

https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm
bla bla bla bla
https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm?id=99061c04-441e-a138-8254-6c441f7f59b5

ulala.

trampampam";
            // WORKS sourcestring = "https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm?id=98061c04-441e-a138-8254-6c441f7f59b5";
            // DOES NOT WORK sourcestring = "https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm?id=98061c04-441e-a138-8254-6c441f7f59b5 ";
            ParseLinksToHtml(sourcestring);


        }
        public static string ParseLinksToHtml(string tekstas)
        {

            string result = tekstas;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                // NOT WORKING Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$");
                //NOT WORKING TOO 
                Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = rx.Replace(result, delegate (Match match)
                {
                    string url = match.ToString();
                    if (url.ToLower().StartsWith("www."))
                    {
                        url = "http://" + url;
                    }
                    return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{1}</a>", url, match.ToString());
                });
            }
            return result;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why not https://[^\s]*|ftp://[^\s]*

Comment: try deleting the "^" at the begining and the "$" at the end  of your pattern

Answer (score 0):

Tested working with the following simplified regex string:

`@"(?:\w+):\/\/(?:[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*"`

Produces:

```
Tralala

bla bla bla

<a href="https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm" target="_blank">https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm</a>
bla bla bla bla
<a href="https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm?id=99061c04-441e-a138-8254-6c441f7f59b5" target="_blank">https://iqesonline.lt/index.cfm?id=99061c04-441e-a138-8254-6c441f7f59b5</a>

ulala.

trampampam
```

Comment: Whose to say that `htttttttts://` isn't a valid protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is this: Removing "^" and "$" made it work. Answer belong to Magnetron. Thank you.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```